# Getting data inside <div><p>data</p></div>

Tags: android, html, dom, jsoup

I am trying to get the data out from the following tag.

I have done this.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(currMsg);
Elements ele = doc.select("p");
```

This returns `<p>data</p>` I want `data` only.

then i tried to traverse an get char by char.

I want to know is there any other way i can get the `data` 
easily.

Comment: I don't get it, you use two lines of code successfully and want to use less?

Comment: hey it is giving me a string <p>data</p> with nodes i dont want node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the text of an element with [Element.text()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29) or [Element.ownText()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29).  text() returns all text inside the element, including inside child elements, while ownText() returns text only in that element (not in any child elements).  [Element.textNodes()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#textNodes%28%29) gives you finer-grained control, if you want some but not all of the text.

The textNodes() Javadoc gives a tiny example showing the relationship between the different ways to get text:

```
For example, with the input HTML: <p>One <span>Two</span> Three <br> Four</p>
with the p element selected:

p.text() = "One Two Three Four"
p.ownText() = "One Three Four"
p.children() = Elements[<span>, <br>]
p.childNodes() = List<Node>["One ", <span>, " Three ", <br>, " Four"]
p.textNodes() = List<TextNode>["One ", " Three ", " Four"]
```

This is covered in the [Jsoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html).  You may find the other sections of the cookbook helpful.